# Datos aleatorios en Blade/Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Quiero generar datos aleatorios en mis vistas, específicamente quiero recorrer los resultados de una consulta y a cada una asignarle un color distinto, todo esto en mis vistas de *[Blade (Laravel)](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/blade-el-sistema-de-plantillas-de-laravel-c111587l/)*.

Algo como esto (parecido a lo que quiero hacer):

```
$array = array('success', 'danger', 'info', 'warning');
$rand = rand(0,3);
echo $array[$rand];
```

Claro, todo esto en *Blade*.

Answer (score 2):

Debes tener en cuenta que Blade no es más que un motor de templates y una especie de wrapper de php básico, por lo cual manejar lógica de negocio en Blade no es la mejor idea.

Para que lo tengas en cuenta, Laravel ya no aplica necesariamente 100% el patrón MVC, eso es parte del pasado, por lo cual el controlador no sería tampoco el lugar ideal para dicho código. Puedes ubicarlo en otra capa como un servicio o un helper.

En todo caso, si quieres definitivamente hacerlo con Blade en la vista, podrías hacer esto:

```
{{ array_rand(['success', 'danger', 'info', 'warning']) }}
```

O puedes armar otra solución similar con shuffle()

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo el *principio de una sola responsabilidad* y el patrón de diseño MVC. La vista solo debe de encargarse de representar los datos que el controlador le manda, no generar los propios.

Entonces desde tu controlador tienes que asignar los colores y simplemente usarlos en tu vista, digamos por ejemplo que obtienes usuarios y a cada uno le añades color. Un enfoque para lograr lo que buscas en tu template sería el siguiente:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p style='color: {{ $user->color }} '> {{ $user->nombre }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por responder. Hice lo siguiente:

//CategoriesController

```
    $categories = Category::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(5);
    $colors = array('success', 'danger', 'info', 'warning');
    shuffle($colors);

    return view('admin.categories.index')->with(['categories' => $categories, 'colors' => $colors]);
```

//Categories/index.blade.php

```
"label label-{{ $colors[rand(0,3)] }}">{{ $category->name }}
```

Con esto solucione, queria esos colores aleatorios, no queria guardarlos en la BD. (Comenten si les parece correcto o si tienen alguna otra idea).

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar una librería especifica para esto:

```
https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker
```

Es una librería que de una forma muy sencilla te permite crear múltiples opciones y textos.

La instalación es sencilla y el uso, mucho mas.

La puedes usar para lo tuyo y para crear mas datos aleatorios.